# How to display the posts of all users on one page

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the code I used in a user's profile page and it works fine

```php
@foreach ($user->posts as $post)
    <div class="col-4 mb-4">
         <a href="{{ route('posts.show', ['post' => $post->id]) }}">
            <img src="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $post->image }}" class="w-100 h-100">
         </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Now I would like to display the posts of all users on the home page

**How to do ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `Post` model in the controller you could something like this.

```php
public function index()
{
   $posts = Post::all();
   return view('home')->with('posts', posts);
}
```

```php
<ul>
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <li>
     <img src="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $post->image }}" class="w-100 h-100">
  </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the post model in your controller like

```
$posts = Post::select('columns_name')->get();
```

compact the variable and you can use like

```
@forelse($posts as $post)
      {{$post->id}}
@empty
   No post found
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the relation in Post model like:

```
public function users()
    {

        return $this -> belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_posts');
    }
```

//where 'user_posts' is your db table with foreign keys

In Controller use:

```
$posts=Post::with('users')->get();
```

Then in view:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="col-4 mb-4">
         <a href="{{ route('posts.show', ['post' => $post->id]) }}">
            <img src="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $post->image }}" class="w-100 h-100">
         </a>
         <a href="{{ route('users.show', ['user' => $post-> user -> id]) }}">
            {{ $post-> user -> name }}
         </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```